# how to provide custom uri and port to send SMS to phone number using twilio sdk library in java?

Tags: java, proxy, twilio, sms, uri

I have to send SMS on phone number from Java function.
I am using below sample code from Twilio site for POC and it's working fine without any issue.

```
public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
      public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);     

        Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("+1111111111"),
            new PhoneNumber("XXXXX"), 
            "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?").create();

        System.out.println(message.getSid());
      }
```

Now I have to pass custom uri which is DP URI with custom port, which is working fine, when i am testing with postman.

but how can i fit here custom URI in this java code?
or do i have to use different code?
or do i have to create my own rest client to work with custom uri?

NOTE: I am using  `implementation 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio:8.18.0'` in build.gradle file. i checked all available options of creator constructor. None of options takes from Number, To Number, Body and URI.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To access the API using the Twilio Java SDK through a proxy requires you to provide an HTTP Client that uses the proxy. This is documented here in [custom documents for the Twilio Java library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java/custom-http-clients-java).

The full code from that article is:

```java
import com.twilio.http.HttpClient;
import com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient;
import com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;


public class ProxiedTwilioClientCreator {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String proxyHost;
    private int proxyPort;
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    /**
     * Constructor for ProxiedTwilioClientCreator
     * @param username
     * @param password
     * @param proxyHost
     * @param proxyPort
     */
    public ProxiedTwilioClientCreator(String username, String password, String proxyHost, int proxyPort) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.proxyHost = proxyHost;
        this.proxyPort = proxyPort;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a custom HttpClient based on default config as seen on:
     * {@link com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient#NetworkHttpClient() constructor}
     */
    private void createHttpClient() {
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(10000)
                .setSocketTimeout(30500)
                .build();

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(10*2);

        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);

        HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        clientBuilder
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .setProxy(proxy)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config);

        // Inclusion of Twilio headers and build() is executed under this constructor
        this.httpClient = new NetworkHttpClient(clientBuilder);
    }

    /**
     * Get the custom client or builds a new one
     * @return a TwilioRestClient object
     */
    public TwilioRestClient getClient() {
        if (this.httpClient == null) {
            this.createHttpClient();
        }

        TwilioRestClient.Builder builder = new TwilioRestClient.Builder(username, password);
        return builder.httpClient(this.httpClient).build();
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like this to, for example, send an SMS message:

```java
// Install the Java helper library from twilio.com/docs/java/install
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
import io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv;


public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.configure()
                .directory(".")
                .load();
        String ACCOUNT_SID = dotenv.get("ACCOUNT_SID");
        String AUTH_TOKEN = dotenv.get("AUTH_TOKEN");
        String PROXY_HOST = dotenv.get("PROXY_HOST");
        int PROXY_PORT = Integer.parseInt(dotenv.get("PROXY_PORT"));

        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        ProxiedTwilioClientCreator clientCreator = new ProxiedTwilioClientCreator(
                ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN, PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);
        TwilioRestClient twilioRestClient = clientCreator.getClient();
        Twilio.setRestClient(twilioRestClient);

        Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("+15558675310"),
                new PhoneNumber("+15017122661"), "Hey there!").create();

        System.out.println(message.getSid());
    }
}
```